# How to select first instance of a class using only CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, squarespace

I am using Square space right now and want to blur the section background image on my home page. The problem is 2 other images on my page are section backgrounds so they all have the same class. To my understanding, I can't directly edit the HTML code to give it an ID. So I need to somehow select the first instance of a class using purely CSS.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [:first-of-type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-of-type) selector

```css
.my-div:first-of-type{color:red}
```

```html
<div class="my-div">One</div>
<div class="my-div">Two</div>
<div class="my-div">Three</div>
```

Comment: Didn't work. All sections backgrounds were blurred

Comment: No way to help without  a [mcve]